# expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'std' in cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I want to use C library in Go. In order to execute C function I need to create C struct. I do it as follows:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    std::uint16_t x;
    std::uint16_t y;
} HeliosPoint;
*/
import "C"

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

When I execute the code I got an error:

```
./main.go:8:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘std’
    8 |  std::uint16_t x;
      |  ^~~
```

How should I modify my code to use above struct?

Comment: Not sure why you have `std::` before the struct variable names. That's not valid C. What happends if you remove that from both the variables?

Comment: See - [golang struct with C struct in CGO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54101022/5291015)

Comment: @Inian you were right, with `std::`, it isn't necessary. I removed it and it works. Thank you.